# Download Google Drive File with BackgroundDownloader - Windows Phone (Universal)

Tags: oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to download a Google Drive File using BackgroundDownloader. I have authenticated the user into drive using REST api and got the access token. My sign in logic goes this way.

```
    public async Task<bool> SignIn()
    {
        var googleUrl = new StringBuilder();
        googleUrl.Append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=");
        googleUrl.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleConstants.ClientId));
        googleUrl.Append("&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
        googleUrl.Append("&redirect_uri=");
        googleUrl.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleConstants.CallbackUrl));
        googleUrl.Append("&state=foobar");
        googleUrl.Append("&response_type=code");

        var startUri = new Uri(googleUrl.ToString());
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, new Uri(GoogleConstants.CallbackUrl), null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
        return true;
    }
```

When I create the BackgroundDownloader, I try to set the request headers - the access token.

```
        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        downloader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "accesstoken");
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(serverLink, UriKind.Absolute), file);
        download.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.Default;
```

But I got Unauthorized error. How am I really supposed to pass my access token to BackgroundDownloader?

[I don't want to use any third party SDK to authenticate and download.]

Comment: Are you sure you formatted the Authorization header correctly? You could try to find info about the error following these steps: https://monkeyweekend.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/how-to-get-the-response-content-of-a-background-transfer-downloadoperation-when-the-result-is-not-200-ok/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. Its the token type I missed in request. The headers should look something like this,

```
downloader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + "accesstoken");
```